# Pyspark 2.2.0 transforming Dataframe to RDD yields different result

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I am having an issue while transforming a DataFrame to an RDD. 
The dataframe is initially constructed from a csv file :

```
columns = 'trip_date;trip_id;op_id;op_abk;op_name;transport_type;train_id;train_service;none;train_service_full;'\
            'additional_trip;failed;stop_id;stop_name;sched_arrival;actual_arrival;arrival_status;sched_departure;' \
            'actual_departure;departure_status;no_stop'.split(';')
    types = [StringType()] * 6 + [IntegerType()] + [StringType()]*3 + [BooleanType()] * 2 +[StringType()] * 8 + [BooleanType()]


    schema = StructType([StructField(name, t, False) for (name, t) in zip(columns, types)])
```

Then read from csv and filter

```
df = spark.read.csv('/datasets/project/istdaten/*/*',schema=schema, sep=';', header=True)

filtered = df.filter(df.stop_id.isin(selected_stops))
```

Selected stops is an array of strings
Then count the stops :

```
filtered.select(filtered.stop_id).distinct().count() [1004 distinct stops]

filtered.rdd.map(lambda r : r.stop_id).distinct().count() [69 distinct stops]
```

I have no clue how can this be. Maybe repartitioning ?

Comment: Which one is the correct number of distinct stops?

Comment: It is 1004.  Transforming to RDD seems to miss a lot of rows (33 times less rows)

Comment: @pissall Do you have any idea why this phenomenon is happening ?

Comment: I tried out the same on some of my data, but the results were same. I had a unique count of 58 (of my data column) in both results. There could be a transformation messing with your count. I think you'll have to post a data snippet and your code. PS. I used the same syntax as you.